# Using javascript/jquery on file input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I have a form with mulitiple file select. I just want send the each file to server via AJAX(selected via multiple select).

I can get the files using

```
document.getElementById('attachment_file').files
```

I want to use something like

```
var files = document.getElementById("attachment_file").files
$.each(files, function(index, file11){
       $.ajax({
        url: "/users",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {doc: {title: file11}},
        async: false,
        success: function() {
        }

      });
});
```

Here I'm not able to pass the file params. any suggesstions

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `FormData` object and send that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData

See the example code here under 'Sending files using a FormData object':

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: good idea but the majority of the browser(s) does not support

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK files are not allowed to be sent to the server via AJAX due to security constraints. Different libraries handle this issue differently - refer to your library docs.

Answer (score 0):

you are not allowed to upload files with plain ajax, typical workarounds either involve flash or the (ab)use o iframes.
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload should be a good library to get you started...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this uploader http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/width/